# Select previous input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I go back to the previous input when hitting backspace on an empty input?

```
    $('input').bind('input', function() {
        if (this.value.length >= $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
            $(this).next().select();
        }

        if (this.value.length == 0) {
            $(this).prev().select();
        }
    });
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/EwYKX/

Comment: You probably shouldn't do this. These kinds of auto-tabbing fields constantly screw up. For example, try changing the letter 'a' to 'b' here: http://jsfiddle.net/EwYKX/5/ Instead just make it all one field.

Comment: Don't you want `focus()`, not `select()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `input` event will not fire if the element already has empty value because there's no value change.

A `keyup` check for backspace press should suffice. Assuming the input elements are always direct siblings as in your example:

```
$('input').on('input propertychange', function() {
    if (this.value.length >= this.maxLength) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 8 && !this.value) {
        $(this).prev().focus();
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EwYKX/4/)

I've added a `propertychange` listener as fallback for old IE, but you can remove it if you don't feel like using this ugly hack to support old IE. Also I've swapped `.select()` by `.focus()` so that it doesn't select the entire field upon focusing, but that is up to you too. `=]`

The `e.which === 8` check is so that it only moves to the previous field by pressing the backspace key, but in case you'd like to move to the previous input even if the user erases the field value through other means (e.g. <kbd>delete</kbd> key or cut/delete context menu) you can remove the `e.which === 8` too, though that wouldn't make much sense UX-wise imho.

Comment: Very informative. Not only did this get the job done, I learned a lot from such a descriptive response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        $('input').bind('input, keydown', function (e) {
           if (this.value.length >= $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
              $(this).next().select();
           }

           if (this.value.length == 0 && e.keyCode == 8) {
              $(this).prev().focus();
           }
        });
```

Comment: I believe you want to use `.on` here